# how can I get user IPs on console.log in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, ip

I want to see the user ips of all users who visit my node site on console.log. Is there a way to do this? I am quite new to node.js, any advise would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get all users in a single `console.log()` because express is stateless. A simple way to capture this is to use a middleware that logs the requesting IP on every request via `req.ip`.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => { 
  console.log(req.ip);
  return next();
});
```